# Waiting for an array of Ajax calls to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple ajax calls that I am making at one time. Once they are **all** done, I need to redirect the user to another page.

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865124/3711901) answer, I created this:

```
function verifyAll() {
    var ajaxCalls = [];
    $.each($('.thing'), function(index, thing) {
        ajaxCalls.push(verifyOne($(thing).data('id'));
    });

    $.when(ajaxCalls).done(function() {
        console.log('Done verifying all');
    });
}

function verifyOne(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'verify.html'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('Done verifying one');
        //do something
    });
}
```

However, the `$.when().done()` function is called BEFORE the `.done()` is called on the individual ajax. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there another way to achieve my end goal?

Comment: use `$.when` to pass it an array of async functions

Comment: Notice the difference between your code which passes an array of deferreds to `when` and the linked code which passes a number of arguments - that is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.when()` doesn't support arrays directly

Try

```
$.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).done(function() {

    console.log('Done verifying all');
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: Or just `$.when(...ajaxCalls)` if you have access to ES6 spread operator.

Comment: @MinusFour that wouldn't work here as the rest operator is used when defining the parameters in the function definition, not when calling the function

Comment: You must be seeing my old comment. I immediately changed it to `spread`.